# hook_form_alter to limit user select list to those referenced in a node

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type called Project. I am linking users to this content type through several user reference fields.

I am also creating related Events (another content type) related to the Project content type pages through the Node Reference URL Widget.

So far so good, but...

In the Event content type I would like to add Attendees, through another user reference field, and limit the list of users to only those referenced in the original Project page. First I tried using a view, but I couldn't find the proper arguments / filters / relationships. Now I am trying through a custom module with hook_form_alter.

Could I get some advice on an efficient way to do this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I have been working on this, and it seems I am almost there, but not quite. Bare with me as this is my first custom module and my php skills are quite basic. My structure (content type > fields) is as follows:

Project:

- field_users (entity reference)

Event

- field_project (entity reference, prepopulated from Project on event
  creation)
- field_attendees (entity reference)

Then, in a custom module, I added the following code to modify the Event content type form:

```
<?php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'project_event_node_form') {
    $id_project=var_export( $form['field_project']['und']['#default_value'][0], TRUE );
    $project = node_load($id_project);
    $user_ref = array();
    foreach($project->field_users as $u){
      $user_ref[] = $u;
    }
    $form['field_attendees']['#options'] = $user_ref;
  }
}
```

But I still see all users, not just those referenced in the Project. Strangely enough, if I do:
dpm($user_ref);
I get this array, which contains the ids of the users I want to be able to choose from:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'target_id' => '7',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'target_id' => '8',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'target_id' => '9',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'target_id' => '10',
    ),
  ),
)
```

But somehow I fail to pass that as the options for field_attendees. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I have narrowed down the problem. The array above that I am trying to pass as options in the form does not seem to have the same structure. The options in the form are like this: 
    #options (Array, 12 elements)
    0 (String, 9 characters ) Anonymous
    $...['field_attendees']['und']['#options'][0]
    2 (String, 10 characters ) drecloshah
    $...['field_attendees']['und']['#options'][2]
    3 (String, 10 characters ) prispehush
    $...['field_attendees']['und']['#options'][3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working:

```
<?php

function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
 if ($form_id == 'project_event_node_form') {
  $node = $form_state['node'];
   if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
    /** This is a new node */
    $id_project=var_export($form['field_project']['und']['#default_value'][0], TRUE);
   }
   else {
    /** This is not a new node */
    $id_project=var_export($form['field_project']['und']['#default_value'][0], TRUE);
    /** horrible hack, but I can't get the nid to behave as an integer no matter what */
    $id_project = substr($id_project, 1, -1);
    /** no need to change the referenced project, hiding the field  */
    $form['field_projet'] = array('#type' => 'hidden');
   }
   /** common code */
   $project = node_load($id_project);
   $user_ref = array();
   foreach(field_get_items('node', $project, 'field_users') as $u){
   $usr_obj=user_load($u['target_id']);
   /** this makes the checkbox form render in a useable way */
   $user_ref[$usr_obj->uid]=$usr_obj->name;
   }
  $form['field_attendees']['und']['#options'] = $user_ref;
 }
}
```

Any suggestions or improvements are welcome, particularly with the dirty hack whith the nid behaving as a string in the node edit.

Although this is a rather simple module it is my first one, so I'd like to thank the patience and support of all those who helped with this, particularly Peyman and Josh at [robustLINKS](http://www.robustlinks.com/), [bnjmnm](http://drupal.org/user/2369194) and [Michael](http://drupal.org/user/1217894).